# Removing Class Name of an element using element.className.replace method

Tags: classname

```
var divfoo=document.getElementById("foo");

divfoo.className=" css-class  css-class2 ";
divfoo.className=divfoo.className.replace(" css-class2 ", "");
```

The above code works. but I would like to make changes to last line of above code which is using replace method. Instead of writing the code like above, I would like to know why doesn't it work when written like below.

```
var divfoo=document.getElementById("foo");

divfoo.className=" css-class  css-class2 ";
divfoo.className.replace(" css-class2 ", "");
```

Why should one assign to "divfoo.className" when applying replace method to the same "divfoo.className", why can't we just apply method directly like above code did?

Because of this should I hate javascript for not being logical?

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is a plain *string* representation of class HTML attribute.

[`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method does not change the source string that is called on, just returns the result of replacement procedure.

If you want more "logical / functional" approach, look at [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface, namely the `remove` method.

Comment: Thanks alot for Answer!